# How to pass parent ID to grandchild

Tags: apex

I have the following structure ; Parent - Child - Grandchild.

From the Child I need to create a new Grandchild via a related list button on the Child that passes an id to the Grandchild.

```
/apex/New_Garandchild?AccId={!Child__c.Id}
```

The Grandchild needs to access fields on the Parent. How can I pass the Parent ID in the above URL to the Grandchild ? It would make my query on the Grandchild easier without having to reference parent related fields in the query .

```
result= [ select Id, ParentField1__c, ParentField1__c
  from Parent__c
  where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')
```

===========

Using this as the button URL to pass the parent ID to the controller:

```
/apex/PROD_Audit_Auto_VehicleSample_New?accId=parentId={!Audit__c.Id}
```

where Audit__c is the parent.

============

```
public with sharing class ParentChildExtensionVEHICLEsample_New {
// Parent= Audit__c, Grandchild= Auto_Vehicle__c

public Audit__c audit;
public Auto_Vehicle__c vehicle;

String accId;
String parentID;

public ParentChildExtensionVEHICLEsample_New(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
{
accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');

// This is the current query that results in an error:  System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
audit= [ SELECT Id, Name, Vehicle_Information__c, Model_Year__c
  FROM Audit__c
  WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId') LIMIT 1
 ];  

}
public Audit__c getAudit() {
return audit;
} 
public Auto_Vehicle__c getVehicle() {
return vehicle;
} 
}
```

Comment: did you consider - (1) Does not Child__c already have a field called parent__c (2) referencing the new field in the URL as in `/apex/newGrandChild?accId={!Child__c}&parentId={!parent__c}`

Comment: Here is the URL I am passing to the controller but getting same message:  /apex/PROD_Audit_Auto_VehicleSample_New?accId=parentId={!Audit__c.Id}           System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
Class.ParentChildExtensionVEHICLEsample_New.<init>: line 16, column 1

Comment: your URL is not valid, there needs to be an `&` before the parameter `parentId`.